# pyinstaller onefile exe and external configuration files

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I created a python software, it uses configuration files in external folder.
I give an example of the folder's structure
--Src
--Src/main.py
--reader
--reader/conf.ini

when I run the comand pyinstaller --onefile main.py the final executable file main.exe connot read from the configuration file reader/conf.ini, but if I run the comand  pyinstaller main.py the executable file main.exe is able to read from conf.ini.
ho can I use both external configuration file and the option --onefile?

Answer (score 1):

Since files are read at runtime instead of compile-time, the config file would need to exist when the executable is ran. If you don't want this, you can hard-code these values as constants into your program, however, the configuration wouldn't be able to be modified unless you re-compile the source code.